# All of my Finder sounds refuse to play

Tags: finder, audio

I installed Lion on launch day, and a few days after, my Finder sounds stopped playing. When I move files, or folders, delete items or empty the trash there is never any accompanying sound. I know this worked under Lion for a while, so I do not thing that the cause is the lion upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further investigation, I discovered that the issue was not confined to Finder sounds but other sounds as well.

I deleted the com.apple.SystemSounds preference file from `~/Library/Preferences`, restarted my computer and it solved the issue.

Comment: I can reproduce this problem, but my sounds did not work a long time before installing lion. I deleted the preference file and restarted my computer, but it did not solve the problem. Do you have any more ideas?